# Figuring out whether a user really closed the browser or not

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm working on a web application in which users are editing shared resources. You can think of Wikipedia articles or Stack Overflow posts as working examples of editable shared resources.

Since users tend not to save their work frequently, there's a problem in which several users can interfere with each other's editing of the same resource. To solve this problem, I'm implementing a locking mechanism, in which a resource is being locked whenever a user starts editing it, meaning that other users cannot edit the resource until the user saves his work. That is, to unlock a resource, a user has to save, or alternatively, exit the browser, in which case his editing is dismissed.

The problem is that when a user closes the browser, a "Leave Site?" dialog pops up, and the user can choose whether to leave or stay. This is a problem, because, starting from a certain version of Google Chrome, I cannot tell whether the user decided to stay or leave, and therefore I can't know if I should really unlock the resource.

What I could've done in older versions of Chrome was to override the default dialog by a custom dialog in which I could've implemented a different behavior depending on whether the user chooses to stay or leave. Unfortunately, I cannot do this for current versions of Chrome, because the function that used to enable this option is deprecated.

Is there a way to differentiate between the case in which the user chooses to leave and the case in which he chooses to stay? Alternatively, is there a better way to implement the locking mechanism such that the resource is unlocked automatically when the user closes the browser?

Comment: Regardless of whether you can detect a browser being closed or not, a network outage, power cut or software crash could all cause the browser to lose connection with the server without the user actively closing the browser. You need to be able to cope with these things, and unlock resources from them. Usually this means having a session timeout.

Answer (score 0):

If your user *actually* leaves the page, an *unload* event will fire.  If they cancel the dialog, then the *unload* event does not fire.  You can use your *unload* event to unlock the resource by [sending a beacon](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon):

```
window.onunload = function () {
    navigator.sendBeacon('/api/unlockResource/12345');
};
```

Unfortunately, mobile Safari does not support beacons yet, and only recent versions of Edge and desktop Safari do, so you may need to try XMLHttpRequest find a workaround if you need that additional support.  You could use a `fetch()` request with `keepalive: true`, for instance, but I'm unable to confirm that mobile Safari supports it.